# Discord API Retrieve members ID in client.on("ready") function

Tags: javascript, discord

I am currently coding a discord bot and have just created a JSON file. This file is to record each members points in a system. I wanted to check within the client.on("ready") function whether a member's points is undefined if so, set it to 0

```
            if (client.points[/*problem*/guild.member.id].points == undefined) {
        client.points [/*problem*/guild.member.id] = {
            points: 0;
        } 
        fs.writeFile("./points.json", JSON.stringify (client.points, null, 4), err => {
            if (err) throw.err;
        });
```

I improvised with "guild.member.id", however, I don't think that is the right way to do it.

**EDIT:** Due to the impossibility and inefficiency of retrieving the User's ID within the `ready` function, I have created an if statement every time a player speaks, which then assigns them to my JSON. This has a benefit of recording whether the user is active or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically don't want to do this every time the bot comes online. Instead, before you do anything related to points, first check if they are saved, if they aren't initialized them with your default values and save them.

https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/json-based-points-system